# Odoo performance, restrict @depends('item.state') not to be triggered if item.state='draft'?

Tags: odoo

- A parent class has a large set of **items** (One2many).
- It also has **a time consuming @depends** function that works on his items that are with a state ['ok', 'canceled'] but that does not works with items in state ['draft']

My issue is that when I create a new items, it starts in 'draft'; so it triggeres the @depends (useless as it does not uses draft items).

**How to make my @depends to skip triggering if a 'draft' items is added ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually trigger it from the sub-model's write function and leave the decoration `@depends` out.

```
def write(self, values):
    res = super(YourClass, self).write(values)
    if 'state' in values and values['state'] in ('ok', 'canceled'):
        for rec in self:
            rec.parent_class_id.function_to_triger()
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you can't.

The long answer: your computed method can start with:

```
for one in self:
    if one.state == 'draft':
        continue
    one.do_things()
```

... or something similar (can't be 100% correct as there's no code sample) to avoid doing things in draft records.

That simple statement will avoid computing costs where unneeded.